2004 Chevy Malibu Ls
2004 Chevy Malibu overheating I’ve changed thermostat the lower intake valve. Got a new reservoir but my old Reservoir someone said it was full of stop leak My new reservoir is also dirty Looks like coffee grounds, same as the old one now it will threaten to overheat it sits at the halfway Mark but it rises up to the next line almost to the red and then it cools back down someone please help me with my issue. I’m thinking that it may be the radiator but then again I have no knowledge of cars.

Does the cooling fan ever turn on with your 20yr old car?  Did you flush the cooling system before or after replacing the t-stat? Beware of flushing the cooling system as this may reveal leaks that weren't addressed when stop leak was installed.

Yes The cooling system has been flushed several times before, and after the thermostat, the car only overheated once or twice and yes, the cooling fan came on

One or two cooling fans? A single cooling fan may run only at one speed whereas dual cooling fans can run up to three speeds.
